# Change CSS class based on number (length) of entity reference items, in a paragraph entity

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

In my paragraph twig file `paragraph--call-to-actions.html.twig`, I want to render and build up the entity reference items (the child items from a certain Paragraph type).

There could be 3 or 4 items. Based on the `length` of the items (3 or 4) I want to change the markup/change a CSS class so I could have 3 or 4 columns.

In `paragraph--call-to-actions.html.twig` I could do something like:

```
{% if content.field_call_to_actions|length == 3 %}
  {# Build 3 column item markup here #}
{% elseif content.field_call_to_actions|length == 4 %}
  {# Build 4 column item markup here #}
```

But how do I loop through my entity reference items (Paragraph type items) so I can print all of the fields of my paragraph type?

Or is there a cleaner approach?

**Update:**
I found a solution by extending `field.html.twig` to `field--paragraph--call-to-actions.html.twig` and in there:

```
{% for item in items %}

  <div class="card mx-6 md:mx-4 mb-6 md:mb-0
  {% if items|length == 3 %}
    md:w-1/3
  {% elseif items|length == 4 %}
    md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4
  {% endif %}
  ">
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

I can't use `loop.lenght` here because of the different breakpoints.

Can I write this more cleaner without duplicate classes (DRY)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by extending field.html.twig to field--paragraph--call-to-actions.html.twig and in there:

```
{% for item in items %}

  <div class="card mx-6 md:mx-4 mb-6 md:mb-0
  {% if items|length == 3 %}
    md:w-1/3
  {% elseif items|length == 4 %}
    md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/4
  {% endif %}
  ">
    {{ item.content }}
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for action in paragraph.field_call_to_actions %}
    {{ paragraph.action.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I found a solution and update my question. With your suggestion I couldn't get the fields visible? Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the [Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) module.

```
{% for action in paragraph.field_call_to_actions %}
    {{ paragraph.action|field_value }}
{% endfor %}
```

or

```
{% for action in paragraph.field_call_to_actions %}
    {{ paragraph.action|field_value|render }}
{% endfor %}
```